# Loading external jpeg images in Tikzedt

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors

Is it possible to display jpeg image in tikzedt editor. The following code gives error.

I add some_image.jpg in tikzedt folder.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{some_image.jpg}};
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (7.5,5.3) rectangle (9.4,6.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you. Saving the image in the same tikzedt folder may be the problem.

Comment: *Which* error? Please specify what the error you get says, one point of error messages is to give hints to what could be the cause of the problem, and that information could make the question possible to answer without guessing.

Comment: It works for me too. I followed first comment of Harish Kumar.

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I converted the comments in to an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since windows vista onwards, the `Program Files` folder has restricted access for security reasons. It seems your tikzedt working directory is inside `Program Files` folder. Hence it is not possible to write the auxiliary files in that folder and `tikzedt` doesn't work it out. On the other hand if the tikzedt working is in the roaming folder (that doesn't have the writing restrictions) things work. In your case, most probably, you are using the tikzedt default working folder and it seems it is inside `Program Files` folder.

Another possibility that it is not working is, you have your image inside a different folder and tex is not able to find the image file.

As a remedy you can create a separate folder elsewhere (different from tikzedt's default working directory), put your `.tex` file and image *both* inside that directory and it should work.